# ResourceDictionary makes use of UserControl -> Resources within UserControl cannot be resolved

Tags: wpf, xaml, user-controls, resources, resourcedictionary

I have Resources defined as a ResourceDictionary in App.xaml:

```
<Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/AssemblyName;component/Resources/HamburgerMenuStyles.xaml" />
                <!--…-->
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <converters:LanguageConverter x:Key="LanguageConverter"/>
            <!--…-->
        </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

Then, in the ResourceDictionary "HamburgerMenuStyles.xaml" that is included in above code I make use of a UserControl:

```
<mah:HamburgerMenu.OptionsItemsSource>
    <mah:HamburgerMenuItemCollection>
        <mah:HamburgerMenuIconItem Label="{localization:Loc tabConf}">
            <mah:HamburgerMenuIconItem.Icon>
                <!--…-->
            </mah:HamburgerMenuIconItem.Icon>
            <mah:HamburgerMenuIconItem.Tag>
                <controls:Settings/> <!--Calling the UserControl here-->
            </mah:HamburgerMenuIconItem.Tag>
        </mah:HamburgerMenuIconItem>
    </mah:HamburgerMenuItemCollection>
</mah:HamburgerMenu.OptionsItemsSource>
```

I get errors, that resources used within the UserControl (the resources used there are also placed in App.xaml) cannot be resolved, eventhough the code compiles and works. How come? I do not get intellisense errors in the UserControl.xaml itsself.

Example:
Visual Studio complains about a converter used in the UserControl which is defined as a resource in App.xaml and does not show any errors in the control xaml + compiles and works.

Comment: In which resource dictionary is the XAML provided above? In which resource dictionary are the resources that produce the errors? Are both of these resource dictionaries included in the App.xaml resources, where?

Comment: I'm not clear where what is from your description. However. If you're getting designer errors due to a resource not being available then that's probably not merged as far as the designer is concerned. You could add a designer only resource.

Comment: Design time only resources: https://antonymale.co.uk/design-time-resources-in-wpf.html

Comment: Hi all, Ive updated my question and tried out Andys suggestion modifying the csproj with the tag <ContainsDesignTimeResources>true</ContainsDesignTimeResources> for HamburgerMenuStyles.xaml. That does not work unfortunately...

Comment: I´ve resolved my problem now, see my answer below. Thanks for trying to help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding the "missing" resource to the control, compiling and then removing the resource again resolved my problem:

```
<mah:HamburgerMenu.OptionsItemsSource>
    <mah:HamburgerMenuItemCollection>
        <mah:HamburgerMenuIconItem Label="{localization:Loc tabConf}">
            <mah:HamburgerMenuIconItem.Icon>
                <!--…-->
            </mah:HamburgerMenuIconItem.Icon>
           <mah:HamburgerMenuIconItem.Tag>
                <controls:Settings>
                    <controls:Settings.Resources>
                        <converters1:InvertBoolConverter x:Key="InvertedBoolConverter"/>
                    </controls:Settings.Resources>
                </controls:Settings>
            </mah:HamburgerMenuIconItem.Tag>
        </mah:HamburgerMenuIconItem>
    </mah:HamburgerMenuItemCollection>
</mah:HamburgerMenu.OptionsItemsSource>
```

This seems to have been a bug somehow. No problems remaining :-)